# org.apache.orc.impl.SchemaEvolution$IllegalEvolutionException: ORC does not support type conversion from file type char(6) (12) to reader

Tags: scala, apache-spark

> Caused by: org.apache.orc.impl.SchemaEvolution$IllegalEvolutionException: ORC does not support type conversion from file type char(6) (12) to reader type struct<_col0:string,_col1:string,_col2:string,....

Comment: used spark 3.0 and the data I am reading from hive partitioned and bucketed table

Comment: Please clearly define your question.

Comment: scala> spark.read.format("orc").load("/apps/hive/warehouse/*****/******/").show(2)                                                                                                               
 While I am trying to read data using spark3 from a hive partitioned and bucketed table on the cluster this above exception is coming.